# AvalonDock: Change Header Height of AnchorablePanes

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

How do I change the height of the headers of all AnchorablePanes preferably at once?

Answer (score 1):

I changed headers styles by overriding its default styles.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:AnchorablePaneTitle}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type xcad:AnchorablePaneTitle}}">
    <!--your style goes here-->
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutAnchorControl}">
    <!--your style goes here-->
</Style>
```